# Trying to find out how to increase my reach in a minecraft 1.12.2 mod

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make a reach enchantment for my Minecraft 1.12.2 mod. I have the code for checking what level the enchantment is, whether it's on, etc. Now my problem is the function. I don't know how to change my reach. I know there's an attribute to do that, but I don't know how to change it. can anyone help me?
This is my code so far:

```
    public static void enchantReachFunction(LivingUpdateEvent event)
    {
        Object player = event.getEntityLiving();
        if(event.getEntityLiving() instanceof EntityLivingBase)
        {
            EntityLivingBase entityPlayer = (EntityLivingBase)player;
            int level = EnchantmentHelper.getEnchantmentLevel(ENCHANT_REACH, entityPlayer.getItemStackFromSlot(EntityEquipmentSlot.CHEST));
            if(!entityPlayer.getEntityWorld().isRemote && level == 1)
            {
                float setBlockReachDistance = 8.0F;
            }

            else if(!entityPlayer.getEntityWorld().isRemote && level == 2)
            {
                float setBlockReachDistance = 12.0F;
            }

            else if(!entityPlayer.getEntityWorld().isRemote && level == 3)
            {
                float setBlockReachDistance = 16.0F;
            }
            else
            {
                float setBlockReachDistance = 4.0F;
            }
        }
    }
```

basically, I'm checking for the level of the enchantment, then increasing the reach based of the level, but it isn't working. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reach is determined by the `REACH_DISTANCE` attribute. You can modify this like so:

```java
EntityPlayer player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().player;
player.getEntityAttribute(EntityPlayer.REACH_DISTANCE).applyModifier(new AttributeModifier(player.getUniqueID(), "custom_reach", setBlockReachDistance, 1));
```

I assume you're changing their reach when they have a tool in their hand with your enchant on it. You would need to track when the player switches to that tool and apply the modifier. When they switch away from the tool, you'll need to remove the modifier like so:

```java
player.getEntityAttribute(EntityPlayer.REACH_DISTANCE).removeModifier(player.getUniqueID());
```

Comment: It looks like this is what I'm looking for, but when I use it, it says: "setBlockReachDistance cannot be resolved to a variable". do you have any ideas for what I can do to fix this?

Comment: That is a float value that represents the reach distance, I put `setBlockReachDistance` there as that's the variable name you were using in your question.

Comment: Then what should I replace it with? I used that because I found something about using it on the web, but I don't actually know what I should use there.

Comment: You should put the reach distance you want the player to have (as a float)

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, but do you mean I should use it like this?

`EntityPlayer user = Minecraft.getMinecraft().player;
          user.getEntityAttribute(EntityPlayer.REACH_DISTANCE).applyModifier(new AttributeModifier(user.getUniqueID(), "custom_reach", 7f, 1));`
When I do, the game crashes

Comment: Yes, that's how you would use it, it's likely crashing because you're setting the modifier before the player is in the world, you need to set it when the player != null.

Comment: Do you mean like this? if(player != null && event.getEntityLiving() instanceof EntityLivingBase) sorry I'm so bad at this, I'm pretty new to coding

Comment: The comments section isn't the best place for this. My post answers your question but it sounds like you could benefit from learning the Java basics first.